# Basic java Game Using 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

http://www.flashbynight.com/drench/

I am trying to make something similar in java using a 2D array and random numbers from 1 to 6 instead of colours, but I am unable to understand how to combine similar numbered tuples. How do I make an algorithm that traverses all same numbered connected tuples?

```
import java.util.*;
class drain
{
    static int g[][]=new int[15][15];
    int prev;
    void newgame()
    {


    }
    void game()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        int chk;
        int in,i,j;
         for(i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<15;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(g[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter color: \n 1:Red \n  2:Blue \n  3:Yellow \n  4: Green \n 5:Purple  \n 6:Black ");
            in=sc.nextInt();
            chk=Ref(in);
        }
        while(chk!=1);
    }
    int Ref(int a)
    {
        prev=g[0][0];
        int flag=1,i=0,j=0,c=0;
        for(i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<15;j++)
            {
                if(g[i][j]==prev)
                {
                     g[i][j]=a;


                }    
                else if(i>0 && j==0)
                {
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        flag=1;
        for(i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<15;j++)
            {
                if(g[j][i]==prev)
                {
                     g[j][1]=a;
                     c++;

                }    
                else if(j>0 && i==0)
                {
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<15;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(g[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


        if(c>=224)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public void main()
    {
       int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<15;j++)
            {
                g[i][j]=(int)(1+(Math.random()*6));

            }
        }

        drain a=new drain();
        a.game();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler approach then yours would be to introduce an additional data structure (like a list), where you store all the fields which you have already visited. Then, when the user inserts a new number, check for every field in your list if its neighbors have the same number.

So, at first you would only have the element (1|1) in your list. Then you check if the field right or at the bottom (or left or top if possible) of it has the same number. If yes, add the field to your list. When you have checked all the neighbors of the current element, continue with the next element in the list. If you reach the end of the list, you are done for this turn.

The game is over when the number of elements in the list is equal to the number of all elements.

This procedure isn't overly complex, so I think you're easily able to write an algorithm out of these instructions yourself :-)